# Deploy Laravel with Sanctum into Heroku - CSRF token mismatch

Tags: heroku, x-xsrf-token, laravel-sanctum

I developed a Laravel+Vue with Sanctum and deployed. On localhost works fine, I can login with my Vue form or with Laravel UI. In Heroku I get a CSRF Token mismatch error if I try to login with my Vue form; if I login with Laravel UI I get a 419 error page.

What I can note is that on my Heroku's app I haven't got any XSRF_TOKEN in my cookies, but in my localhost I have. I tried changing session driver from file to database driver as I read that in Heroku file driver doesn't work fine because of its storage system, with the same results (CSRF Token mismatch and not XSRF-TOKEN).

I also tried with http and https.

Comment: I currently have this problem, where you able to find a solution?

Answer (score -3):

app/Http/Kernel.php in protected $middlewareGroups

```
// \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the answer to the question. Can you elaborate?